# Dynamic page url using jsf

Tags: jsf

I need a page with URL that is dynamic. Let's suppose user profile page.

**Example :**

- URL for user profile (salah) socail.com/salah and page must appear salah data
- URL for user profile (wael) socail.com/wael and page must appear wael data

How can I do this using JSF framework .

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirement?What you have tried so far?

Comment: i need to my page with dynamic url just as web service when you request url such as https:\\www.site.com\welcome suppose it return json response
such as " you entered welcome " what i need to do like that but in my jsf application how to make dynamic url

Comment: I think what you need is http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/. Way easier and flexible than doing things in home grown servlet(filters)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a servlet with mapping appropriate for your needs, something like this:

`@WebServlet("/")`

Then when someone enters URL like `yourpage.com/<anything here>` then this servlet is gonna handle the request. To get a username from that url you need to do something like:

`String username = request.getRequestURI().substring(1)` - that is gonna get request info without the hostname and strip `/` from it.

Set the parameter (your info) so you can retrieve that in JSF:

`request.setAttribute("userInfo", getSomeInfoByUsername(username));`

Then you can forward the request to your JSF view file, like this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("faces/index.xhtml").forward(request,response);
```

Then in JSF file you can do something like this to get the info from request:

`<h:outputText value="#{requestScope.userInfo}"/>`

If I didn't miss anything those are all the pieces you need, getting username from URL can probably be retrieved in a better way, but nothing comes to my mind right now.

[More about servlets here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: thanks your answer helpful , in your answer you write requestScope this is your managedBean and it have userInfo field and when you do that request.setAttribute("userInfo", getSomeInfoByUsername(username));        it's intialize my requestScope Bean that's correct ?

Comment: No, requestScope is implicit object, it's already built in JSF, check this http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html

Comment: @salahatwa If you liked it please read [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thanks!

Comment: Will this keep the view state based on the url in a @ViewScope?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,you want to dynamically redirect the control on the basis of request/session attributes:

You can take help of `ExternalContext`. For example:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "userProfile.jsf?user=" + user);
```

user is the attribute passed through backing bean.

Having said that I assume that you have already worked with JSF.

Comment: Dear downvoater,Kindly mention the reason!